# Jquery Ajax load/post

Tags: ajax, jquery

Im trying to get the `.load` method to post to a page and then echo back what was posted to see if it is working, i can't get this to work.  I tells me that the variable is undefined, here is what i have:

teachers.php:

```
<?php
echo $POST['class'];
```

The JS:

```
$('#test').load('teacher.php', {class: 'test'});
```

That is triggered once something is clicked.

`#test` is a `<div>` that I want the data to post to.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're using the wrong method for this. Use `$.post()` or `$.ajax()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `$_POST` instead of `$POST`.  Don't know if that was a typo, but that will also create some issues.

Comment: Wrong. If an object is passed instead of a querystring, it uses POST and not GET. Much like in the OP's example.

Comment: I guess it tends to help when i type the right thing.  I hate it when its something simple like that and don't realize it.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: We've all done it. Sometimes just needs another eye.  Cheers.

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times problems like these are due to the **asynchronicity** of AJAX.
Everything you load via AJAX (with `.post()`, `.load()`, `.ajax()`, `.get()`) doesn't "exist" unless the AJAX round trip of request-response has been completed.

Be sure to "use" what you load with AJAX (a HTML bit, a JSON response, ...) *in a callback function*, that is called on the *success* of the AJAX request.

For example let's say my page `ajax.php` returns this string: `<div id='ajaxdiv'>hello!</div>`, we want to load this (HTML) string in `#mydiv`:

```
$("#mydiv").load("ajax.php");
console.log($("#mydiv #ajaxdiv")); <- undefined
```

It won't work because the code continues regardless of the completion of the request. Instead:

```
$("#mydiv").load("ajax.php", function () { console.log($("#mydiv #ajaxdiv"));});
```

works because JQuery makes sure to use the *callback function* only if the request has been completed.
(You can also add parameters like your `{class: test}`, just put them between the URL and the callback function).

Edit: use $_POST and not $POST.

Answer (score 0):

if your just trying to post information from jQuery to a PHP file when something with the id of `test` is clicked then do this:

teachers.php:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['class'];
?>
```

The JS:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
    $.post('teacher.php', {class: 'test'},
        function(output) {
            //output = what is echoed from the php file.
            alert(output);
        );
});
```